# Probability of rolling 3 Dice .

Tags: probability

i have 3 fair cubic dice. I roll it for 3 times ( ie. 9 dice ) . What is the probability of getting atleast one dice facing with 6 in of those 3 trials ? Is that probability same for other numbers as well ?

Comment: Give us more information about what you tried!

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the complement: what is the probability of getting no $6$ in these $3\cdot 3$ rolls?

P.S. At the end you should find the required probability is $1-(5/6)^9$. This probability does not change if you replace $6$ with another number among $1,2,3,4,5$.